# Slack API: Escape asterisk character in payload

Tags: markdown, slack-api

I have a web app that triggers a Slack notification. I intend to send the formatted text below on Slack:

> 500 * 2 = **1000**

To achieve this, I post the data below to [Slack PostMessage API](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage):

```json
{
    "channel": "CHANNEL_ID",
    "type": "mrkdwn",
    "text": "500 * 2 = *1000*"
}
```

Clearly, there is a markdown issue as the first asterisk is not escaped. To fix this, I tried passing the text as shown below:

```json
"text": "500 \\* 2" = *1000*
```

..and then, I got this output:

> 500 \* 2 = **1000**

Using only one backslash returns this error:

```json
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_json",
    "warning": "missing_charset",
    "response_metadata": {
        "warnings": [
            "missing_charset"
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try this: ` text": "5 * 2 = *1000*" ` ?

Comment: I want the "1000" to be bold.

Comment: sorry SO formatting changed it to *italics* : ` text": "5 * 2 = * 1000 *" ` i.e. with spaces between 5 & 2 but without spaces with 1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using U+2217, the Asterisk Operation character. Here it is for copy-pasting:

```
∗
```

Comment: How to escape other Slack formatting characters such as `_` or `~`?